# a custom title for the fragment

Tags: android

Good afternoon, please tell me how you can set a custom title for the fragment in Android Studio? I use this code: public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
public FirstFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    Button aboutBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);
  
    aboutBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.aboutButton:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            replaceFragment(fragment);
            break;

       ....
    }
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

}
When I tried to use title="Name1"; this is not works. then if use getActivity().setTitle("Name1"); it works, but when press the back button the title remains unchanged

Comment: getActivity().setTitle("Fragment Name"); in your onResume of each fragment may solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    // Add this line here to change title 
    getActivity().setTitle("your title");

    Button aboutBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);
  
    aboutBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    return rootView;
}
```